# /proc/net/tcp: permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

When I type `netstat` into my SSH console as a non root user, I get

> /proc/net/tcp: permission denied

but it works fine as root. I was wondering if it's possible how I would allow non root users to run this command.

Using Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Is target yours or are you connecting a third party server?? (In the second case, migrating from serverfault was probably not a good idea!)

Answer (score 1):

It should be readable by default, make sure you don't have weird mount options in `/etc/fstab` or some clumsy post-mount task in `/etc/init/mounted-proc.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe connected to a paranoid server, protected strongly against [TURLA FOR LINUX](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74695/15701) viruses.

This could be restricted by some `apparmor` protections.

You could try my [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) prototype of [turla knockdoor sample](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/76545/15701) to understand how access to `/proc/net/tcp` could become a way of attack...

Ask your sysadmin (and tell im to read my answer in order to protect his system)!